# Linq "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, linq, null

Am a little lost on this one.  Getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the line `db.EntityRichContents.DeleteAllOnSubmit(q);` at runtime.  Project builds fine.

```
protected override void ControllerOnEntityDeleted(EntityObj forEntity, EntityDeletionController.DeletionAction newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == EntityDeletionController.DeletionAction.HardDelete)
    {
        if(forEntity == null) throw new Exception();

        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            var q = db.EntityRichContents.Where(c => c.C3Entity == ForEntity.TypeID && c.C3EntityRecordID == ForEntity.ID);
            db.EntityRichContents.DeleteAllOnSubmit(q);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Checking `q.Any()` or `q == null` doesn't help in any way (q isn't null).

Comment: What object is it saying is null?

Comment: @Brandon not a duplicate.  Both `q`, `db` and `forEntity` are not null

Comment: What does q.Any() return?

Comment: What happens if you `.ToList()` the `Where` call before the `DeleteAllOnSubmit`?

Comment: `forEntity` != `ForEntity`.  Is this a typo?

Comment: @DavidL doh that's it!  Thank you!

Comment: what about `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there are two similar variables: one is **ForEntity** (possibly a class property property?) and the second being **forEntity** (method parameter). Is that a typo?

Either way, given that the *Where* method is enumerated lazily I would assume that one of the lambda parameters in 
`(c => c.C3Entity == ForEntity.TypeID && c.C3EntityRecordID == ForEntity.ID)`
is null. Try adding null-checks for every parameter and/or property to avoid exceptions.